# Second task in run-sequence doesn't run

Tags: node.js, gulp, run-sequence

Suppose I have the following task:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function (cb) {
    fs.appendFileSync('myPath', 'data');
});
```

When I do something like this:

```
gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
    runSequence('my-task', 'some-task',cb);
});
```

`my-task` runs and finishes, but `some-task` never runs.

My question is: how do I make `some-task` run after `my-task` has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that gulp doesn't notice that `my-task` has finished. When you declare a callback function `cb` you have to actually call the callback:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function (cb) {
  fs.appendFileSync('myPath', 'data');
  cb();
});
```

Or you can leave the callback out entirely, since `fs.appendFileSync` is synchronous anyway:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function () {
  fs.appendFileSync('myPath', 'data');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice trick of leaving the callback out entirely. So what's the logic behind this? can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Tasks are always synchronous unless you use [one of the three ways of hinting asynchronous behaviour](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support)